# Touchpad lag while using Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I have this trouble for a while, and it is the only reason I have not deleted my Windows partition.
While on Chrome (it hasn't happened in other applications I believe), the touchpad gets dramatically laggy. The speed and accuracy are fine, it just literally takes the pointer a second or 2 to follow my movements in the touchpad.

Specs: Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 14 (newer model), Ubuntu 16.04 and recently 16.10. I have updated the kernels to the latest stable version. 
I have the latest Chrome version (54)
Related: The wireless mouse works perfectly, the red Thinkpad pointer also works well. (An issue here though is that the red pointer and the mouse are controlled by the same settings. So while the red point is hard to maneuver which encourages me to set the setting on fast, the mouse becomes too fast too control).

Another issue is when scrolling with an external mouse too fast the websites sort of go back up and down again like flickering (even though I am scrolling down).

Please please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lag also appeared in other applications, especially browsers.
Solution was to modify a parameter in xinput of touchpad device.

```
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Device Accel Profile"
```

Comment: In my Dell XPS 13, using: `xinput set-prop "DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad" "Device Accel Profile"` tells me: `Usage: xinput set-prop <device> [--type=atom|float|int] [--format=8|16|32] <property> <val> [<val> ...]` ... any ideas?

Comment: @Alo you do know that the command you wrote does not work, right ?

Comment: @seza443 yeah it was a temporary fix then, but after a few months it stopped working.. :(